# execl: couldn't exec `/bin/sh'

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sh, exec

I accidentally moved the whole bin, boot, dev and etc directory.
After moving everything back I get the following error email from various cron jobs:

`` execl: couldn't exec `/bin/sh' ``
`execl: No such file or directory`

Command used to move the directories:

`mv /* /some-folder`

`ls -l /bin/sh`
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 22  2013 /bin/sh -> bash`

`ls -l /bin/bash`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 938832 Jul 18  2013 /bin/bash`

Comment: What commands did you use to move the directories? Could you post the output of `ls -l {/usr,}/bin/sh`?

Comment: Hi, i added the output of ls -l /bin/sh to the question.
ls -l {/usr,}/bin/sh is outputing a error:
`ls: cannot access /usr/bin/sh: No such file or directory  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 22  2013 /bin/sh -> bash`

Comment: You you post `ls -l /bin/bash` as well? Did you try restarting the machine?

Comment: Added the output of  ls -l /bin/bash. I did not try to restart the machine yet, because i'm nog allowed to.

Comment: I see. Moving around the directories might have had a lot of unexpected consequences. Services might have been terminated because they couldn't read configuration files or execute binaries, and I'm not entirely sure that all special files inside `/dev` will function properly after moving them around. If all files are once again where they belong (and, at least, `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` seem to be), I'd say your best bet is a restart.

Comment: OK, thank you for you help. Hope the system will restart after the moving :)

Comment: Plausible scenario: the messages were generated when there was no `/bin/sh` but the e-mails were only processed after you fixed things, because some recurring procedure relied on some tool you broke; it failed at least once but after you moved the directories back it managed to deliver the stale messages. This is why you got them *after* the fix.